# Ways to fasten gurobipy's `Model.computeIIS()`

Tags: python, gurobi

We are using Gurobi solver to solve our large-scale(~15K constraints) QCQP problem.

Gurobi declares the problem as `infeasible` within 2 minutes, but unfortunately it is unable to compute the [IIS set](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_computeiis.html) within reasonable time (we terminated it after exceeding 1.5 hours).

Is there any way(s) to fasten the IIS computation?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no: it can take a lot of time to compute an IIS. You could try using feasRelax to relax some constraints.

Comment: Thanks Greg! Some speculations: 1) Would increasing n_threads help for speedup? 

2) How to programmatically (without manual interrupt) can we get an [intermediate IIS](http://gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_computeiis.html#:~:text=If%20an,point) computed within a timeout of 1.5 hrs?

Comment: In general, it's best to leave Threads at its default value; higher values is far more likely to hurt than help. As for an intermediate IIS result, unfortunately your only realist option is to set a TimeLimit.